# How to use Visual Studio Autoformat from script?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, scripting, powershell, format

We all know Visual Studio's **Edit > Format Document** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

Is it possible to use Powershell (or any other script) to run this on a number of .cs files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not same thing as VS, but there is NArrange:

http://www.narrange.net/

It is console based.